# IntelliJ/PhpStorm only switches keyboard layout by half

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, dvorak, qwerty

I'm having a strange problem with IntelliJ IDEA 16.1.2 running in Ubuntu MATE 16.04: when I switch between keyboard layouts, then normal typing works as expected, but any control key combinations use the wrong layout. Confused? So am I.

For years I've been using MATE (Linux Mint MATE, Ubuntu MATE) and switching between layouts (Norwegian Dvorak and US English) via MATE's built-in keyboard layout switcher (using <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to switch globally), and this has been working without a single hitch. I love it.

But now I started using IntelliJ, and I find that when I switch layouts, <kbd>a o e u</kbd> becomes <kbd>a s d f</kbd> as it should, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X / C / V</kbd> and all the others remain on the Dvorak key positions (that is, on qwerty you'd have to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B / I / ></kbd> in order to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X / C / V</kbd> on the Dvorak layout. Ditto for all other <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>any key</kbd> commands such as Find, Print, etc.

This is bonkers! And it's only happening in IntelliJ IDEA and PhpStorm. I've never seen this before, and right now those are the only two apps on my system that are affected.

---

My keyboards are native QWERTY, and I have used the OS to specify Dvorak as the primary layout, with QWERTY as an option and a hotkey to toggle between them.

I use Dvorak almost exclusively; the only reason to have the other layout is for "guests": coworkers during pair work, and my wife on the systems at home.

Dvorak is working 100%, but the querty is not: the querty works for non-ctrl characters, but ctrl stays mapped to Dvorak

Comment: Oooh, it seems there's a way to [use different layouts on different keyboards](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6266103/367605), how interesting! I'll give this a go.

Comment: ...sadly, that approach didn't work so well. I still have a problem.

Comment: What type of keyboard do you have? (dvorak or querty) If dvorak, does it have normal scan-codes?

Comment: I have various keyboards: ThinkPad laptops, wireless Logitech keyboards, wired keyboards. This is not hardware related. It's now two years later, and still an issue, but only affects my "guests" when pair programming. So, usually I will do the typing.

Comment: sorry you did not answer my clarification question (it is relevant). Your keyboards, are they regular querty, or regular dvorak, or dvorak with hardware remapping, or …

Comment: You say that it only affects your peer when pair programming. Which layout do they use?, which layout do you use?

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean -- my keyboards are native QWERTY, and I have used the OS to specify Dvorak as the primary layout, with QWERTY as an option and a hotkey to toggle between them.

Comment: I use Dvorak almost exclusively; the only reason to have the other layout is for "guests": coworkers during pair work, and my wife on the systems at home.

Comment: **Am I correct in saying** “Dvorak is working 100%, but the querty is not: the querty works for non-ctrl characters, but ctrl stays mapped to Dvorak”?

Comment: That is exact, yes. (Also, thanks for your edits.)

Comment: Note you can edit your own question. Don't wait for me to copy your comments to the question. Just edit the question, and comment to tell me that there is an update.

Comment: This question may get a better answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is for the other way around, but may help.

I have seen a setting, where you can switch to dvorak, but key control keys in querty position. I think it is in the keyboard layout system-settings.